# Order by is slow for LIMIT X (but fast for LIMIT X-1)

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

I know there are many questions already posted to this topic, but I haven't find a solution for my problem.

I have just one table that has 1.042.162 rows.
Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbllinks` (
  `idLinks` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `linksText` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `linksLastChecked` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `linksLastNewData` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idLinks`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idtblLinks_UNIQUE` (`idLinks`),
  UNIQUE KEY `linksText_UNIQUE` (`linksText`),
  KEY `fasterDate` (`linksLastChecked`),
  KEY `faster2` (`linksText`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3029595 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This one:

```
SELECT * FROM tbllinks order by linksLastChecked asc limit 9324;
```

needs 0.094 sec.
And this one:

```
SELECT * FROM tbllinks order by linksLastChecked asc limit 9325;
```

needs 42.559 sec.

Both querys only return "Null" values in the linksLastChecked column (what is right), but most datasets have a Value.
There is also nothing special about the dataset 9325. So i realy have no idea why its so much longer for just one Dataset more.

 
 
**Edit:**
 
With explains it makes sence why it needs so long.

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbllinks | index | NULL          | fasterDate | 6       | NULL | 9324 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------+
```

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra          |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbllinks | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 805031 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
```

The first one is using the index key, the scond one not! But i have still the question why that and why the second one is unsing 805031 rows?

 
 
**Edit: (Answer)**
 
Ok sorry that I even ask. I just searched with the wrong question.
While searching for "mysql doesn't use index" i found this nice article.
http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/7-ways-to-convince-mysql-to-use-the-right-index
while `USE INDEX` didnt worked for me, `FORCE INDEX` helped.

Comment: View the explain for both queries.